# What does changing TFS Build Quality do exactly?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

This question is a bit round about, but I'll get to that in a minute.   When someone changes the build's quality in TFS (we're on 2005) what exactly happens?   Does this affect changesets or workitems, notifications??

Now the reason I ask:  I want to be able to generate a changeset list between builds. As such selecting a build on Jan 1 and comparing it to a build on March 29, I want all the changesets between those builds.   Perhaps there is another way to do this but I do think the build is the starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, it's just meta data about the build.  The intent being you can use it in your development process to indicate when a build has progressed through certain quality gates.

It should be noted that the open source TFSDeployer project relies on the build quality as a trigger mechanism to run deployments scripts.

Comment: I'd love to see an example of the quality gates you described.  You wouldn't, by any chance, know where I could read more on that do you?

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2012, you can set a quality threshold on builds to say which ones can be used by Microsoft Test Manager for testing.
In MTM, in the Testing Center, under the Plan tab, under the Properties subtab, there is a section called Builds. You set a quality threshold with "Filter for builds" and then any builds that conform to the filter will show up when you click Modify under the "Build in use" line.

On a side note, I have found some interesting info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/030a9cc7-4c91-4132-a9fa-0fbcf119218d/tfs2010-team-build-automatically-update-build-quality) about automatically updating build quality through XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a notes field. I see it show up on some reports, but nothing else of value.